# How to provide for IPC API backward compatibility

Tags: concurrency, ipc, backwards-compatibility

I am designing a (SOAP-like) inter-process communication protocol for making function calls over a network. I want to make sure an older client can talk to a newer server. After thinking over it for a while, it seems like the only thing I can do are:

- avoiding API changes
- make it possible to add functions
- make it possible to add function parameters

However, when the server's functionality thoroughly changes, this isn't enough. For example:

- a parameter that has to be moved from one function call to another.
- a parameter type that changes, for example from an integer to a string.

My question is: can this kind of changes be made while staying backward compatible, or is the only option simply not to make them?

**Note:** I know, I am suffering from the [not invented here syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here), but in my opinion that doesn't invalidate this question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said exactly how you are implementing the IPC, so I might be making some poor assumptions here.  Anyway, off the top of my head, there are a couple approaches to an issue like this.

First, regarding the point of parameter order/type changing, you can use a dynamic language like Python to get around this.

```
>>> def discriminant(a,b,c):
...     return b*b - 4*a*c

>>> discriminant(1,8,2)
56
>>> 
>>> discriminant (c=2, a=1, b=8)
56
```

Python allows you to use named parameters so that you can name variables in any order you like, and all variables are dynamically typed.

A less efficient approach to the ordering issue might be to pass all arguments in as a dictionary (written in Python, but can be adapted for whichever language):

```
>>> def disc2(in_dict):
...     return in_dict['b']*in_dict['b'] - 4 * in_dict['a'] * in_dict['c']
... 
>>> d = dict(a=1, b=8, c=2)
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 8}
>>> disc2(d)
56
```

To expand upon *this* idea, you could also contain a "version" field in your dictionary (or arguments, whatever) to allow the server to adjust accordingly to the incoming arguments.  It doesn't have to be a dictionary, you could put a version field in the packet containing the IPC message as well.  This might be a contrived example, but you could account for missing fields this way as well.

```
>>> def disc3(d):
...     if d['version'] == 1: # original spec
...             return d['b'] * d['b'] - 4 * d['a'] * d['c']
...     else: # newer clients returning smaller values of c
...             return d['b'] * d['b'] - 4 * d['a'] * (2*d['c'])
... 
>>> d['version'] = 1
>>> disc3(d)
56
>>> d['version'] = 2
>>> disc3(d)
48
```